# Is there a way to test functions with Jasmine without exposing them?

Tags: node.js, jasmine

I have a `utils.js` file with some generic utility functions. I use `module.exports` to expose some of the functions while keep the rest hidden.

```
module.exports = {
utils_1: function_1,
utils_2: function_2
};
```

Suppose there are other functions, namely `function_3` and `function_4` that I would like not to expose, yet I want to test with Jasmine. The only way I can currently do it is by exposing them with the rest of the functions and writing my test suites as usual.

Is there a way to test some functions via Jasmine while not exposing them?

The only thing I can think of is creating a different javascript file containing (and exposing) `function_3` and `function_4`, require that file in my `utils.js` and at the same time test the new file with Jasmine, but this would split my original file in two (and the same would apply for all other similar files).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`function_3` and `function_4` are used inside `function_1` and `function_2`, right? So, do you really need to unit test it? I would not. But other people might think the contrary.

Here is my example

```
// utils.js
function function_3(obj) {
  obj.a = 3;
  return obj;
}

function function_4(obj) {
  obj = function_3(obj); // invoke function_3
  obj.b = 4;
  return obj;
}
module.exports = { utils_4: function_4 };
```

The test:

```
const { utils_4 } = require('utils');

describe('test 1', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const obj = utils_4 ({});

    expect(obj.a).toBeDefined();
    expect(obj.a).toEqual(3);

    expect(obj.b).toBeDefined();
    expect(obj.b).toEqual(4);
  });
});
```

It should pass, right? See that I only test `function_4`, but, if I change the implementation of `function_3` in a way that brakes my test, the test will detect it.

If we change `function_3` to

```
function function_3(obj) {
  obj.c = 3;
  return obj;
}
```

The test will fail.

This is an awful example but it is just illustrative. Take the good part of it. But again, other people might think the contrary and will go with an approach to test `function_3` directly. Use a coverage lib to see what is covered by your tests.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Your private / unexposed functions are used within your exported functions, are they not? Thereby, they are tested implicitly as soon as you write all the test cases for your public / exposed functions.

Exposing functions or writing tests on private functions is missing the goal of unit tests: Testing the *public interface*.

Think of private / unexposed methods as implementation details. You should not write tests for those, as the private methods are abstracting the implementation detail. It becomes tedious and over-complicated to have tests break because some internal behavior changed slightly.

You should be able to refactor or rewrite private functions at a whim, yet as long as they public interface is fulfilled, your tests shall remain green.

It may make sense to create a new module for your function_3 and function_4, depending on what they are doing for you. If I discover, that I want to test something internally, that's a sign to make it into its own module, with its own public interface.

So I'd say that your intention of moving the functions into a different JavaScript file is actually the right idea. (Yet you may realize that here only `function_3` needs to be exposed, whereas `function_4` can still be hidden).